# Run a compiled program using ajc

Tags: java, aspectj

I have written two simple codes..one java code to print a Hello World statement and other a aspect code to be weaven into it..

My hello world code is

```
// HelloWorld.java
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String args[]){
   say("Hello world");

}
public static void say(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}    
public static void sayToPerson(String message, String name) {
    System.out.println(name + ", " + message);
}
}
```

and my aspect code is..

```
public aspect MannersAspect {
pointcut callSayMessage() : call(public static void HelloWorld.say*(..));
before() : callSayMessage() {
    System.out.println("Good day!");
}
after() : callSayMessage() {
    System.out.println("Thank you!");
}
}
```

I have saved both into HelloWorld.java and MannersAspect.java and have compiled it using ajc *.java

It has given me two classes HelloWorld.class and MannersAspect.class

Now the major question for me is "HOW TO RUN IT"?

Please help me with this.I am stuck.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured It out..:P:P

I saw it on a website and it was like..

```
ajc -argfile <fullpath>\myList.lst
```

where myList.lst contained both files like this

```
HelloWorld.java
MannersAspect.java
```

And then doing java HelloWorld

Cheers